# activar automáticamente modal bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, div, yii2

buenos dias tengo un pequeño codigo `html` para llamar una ventana `modal` 
al cargar y hago `alerts`  antes y despues y los manda excepto el `modal`

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
function redireccionar(){
  alert("1");
  document.getElementById('id01').style.display='active';
  alert("p2");
} 
setTimeout ("redireccionar()", 1000); //tiempo expresado en milisegundos
</script>
```

probe de esta manera

```
<button id="id01" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
```

y esta otra

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
```

este es el div

```
<div id="id01" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div  class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div  class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div id="id01" class="modal-body">
        <img class="third-slide" src="../img/cat_001.png" alt="Third slide">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No veo myModal en ninguna parte.  Que no tendria que ser id01?

Comment: reemplazo el `id01` por el `mymodal` y no lo llama

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funciona si simplemente usas el id correcto asi:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function redireccionar(){
  alert("1");
  document.getElementById('id01').style.display='active';
  $("#id01").trigger("click");
} 
setTimeout ("redireccionar()", 1000); //tiempo expresado en milisegundos
</script>

<button id="id01" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div  class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div  class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div id="id01" class="modal-body">
        <img class="third-slide" src="../img/cat_001.png" alt="Third slide">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: el botón me funciona bien lo que necesito es que el `js` active ese `boton` y es lo que no logro

Comment: ya edite mi respuesta

Comment: ok, muchas gracias ahora si